# MySQL shell for VS Code rootCA.crt certificate error

Tags: mysql, certificate, mysql-shell

I installed mysql on my Pop OS machine and since I prefer every thing to be in visual studio code I installed mySQL shell extension for VSCode but I get this [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fLaap.png) when I open it.
it says `Failed to connect please check if rootCA.crt certificate is installed on your local system`

I tried the instructions in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate#:%7E:text=Ubuntu%20Install%20Certificate%201%20Create%20a%20directory%20for,%2Fetc%2Fca-certificates.conf%20%3A%20sudo%20dpkg-reconfigure%20ca-certificates%20...%20See%20More.) to install
the rootCA.crt file in  `~/.mysqlsh-gui/plugin_data/gui_plugin/web_certs/rootCA.crt`
but it didn't work 
note: I did restart VS Code.

Comment: Are you running on a ssh-remote VS Code session ? If so, go to Settings->Extensions, MySQL Shell for ... and on the _Distant [SSH:<name>]_ tab uncheck _Msg > Shell : Enforce Https_